# How to download blobs from Azure storage to the browser. Using ASP.NET MVC 4.8

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Hi I am using Azure blob storage and upload.  Using ASP.NET MVC 4.8 to upload/download files.
I want to know how I can download files without specifying the path to download. That means I want to download the files into browser download folder.

I am able to download the files using :

```
 BlobDownloadResult downloadResult = blobClient.DownloadContent();
 return downloadResult;
```

and

```
blobContainerClient.DownloadTo(path); //but I don't want to download to 
                                       //local folder
```

But trying to figure out how I can download in browser.
I also need to consider I may have situation there files are big e.g  4 gig.

Update:
After posting the above question. This is what I did to download the file. I would like someone who can improve this solution.  I am thinking I may be doing something that is overkill.

```
 public BlobDownloadResult DownLoad(string fname, string containerName)
    {

            BlobContainerClient containerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(containerName);
            BlobClient blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(fname);
            BlobDownloadResult downloadResult = blobClient.DownloadContent();
            return downloadResult;  

        }
    }
```

in aspx page:   I am using Webform:

```
 public void DownloadFileToBrowser()
  {
    var blobDownloadResult = azStorageBlob.DownLoad(fileName, containerName);

                var content = blobDownloadResult.Content.ToStream(); 
                var byteas = blobDownloadResult.Content.ToArray();
                var lengthss = blobDownloadResult.Details.ContentLength;
                var arraylenght = blobDownloadResult.Content.ToArray().Length;

                long dataLengthToRead = content.Length;
                Response.ContentType = "application/force-download";
                Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");
                while (dataLengthToRead > 0 && Response.IsClientConnected)
                {
                    int maxSlice = 320 * 1024;
                    var lengthRead = content.Read(byteas, 0, maxSlice);
                    Response.OutputStream.Write(byteas, 0, lengthRead);
                    Response.Flush();
                    dataLengthToRead = dataLengthToRead - lengthRead;
                }
                Response.Flush();
                Response.Close();
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

To enable downloading files from Azure Blob Storage directly to the browser's download folder without specifying a path, you can use the Content-Disposition header with the value attachment in the HTTP response. This header instructs the browser to treat the response as a downloadable file and prompts the user to save it.

```
// Set the response content type based on the file's MIME type
Response.ContentType = blob.Properties.ContentType;

/
```

Comment: If you can also show *how* to set that header, that would be great

Answer (score 0):

### **In the above example, you need to replace "your_connection_string" with your actual Azure Blob Storage connection string and "your_container_name" with the name of your container. By setting the Content-Disposition header to "attachment", the browser should prompt the user to save the file to their download folder. Note that downloading large files (e.g., 4 GB) directly from the Azure Blob Storage might not be optimal due to potential timeouts and performance issues. In such cases, you may want to consider implementing a streaming approach or providing the user with a temporary download link that expires after a certain period.**

Comment: Please see my update and see if I can improve download to browser functionality.